# Deep Link is not working on Some browser React Native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am trying to add deep link and universal linking to my react native app. I am listening to url in my App component as follows:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    ...

    Linking.getInitialURL()
      .then(ev => {
        if (ev) {
          handleOpenURL(ev);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn('An error occurred', err);
      });

    const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);

    return () => {
      ...
  subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

 <NavigationContainer
  linking={{
    prefixes: ['onedollardeal://', 'https://onedollardeal.pk'],
  }}
  ...
</NavigationContainer>
```

But from Google Chrome it doesn't detect the both, from DuckDuckGo it detects the deeplink but not the universal link. When i tried from cmd using adb command it also gets detected. What I am doing wrong here?
My ManifestFile is like below:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="onedollardeal.pk" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="onedollardeal" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="onedollardeal.pk" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="onedollardeal.pk" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="onedollardeal" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ....
</manifest>
```

EDIT: Sorry DuckDuckGo detects both but Google Chrome is not detecting any of the links. Could this be related to being default browser or not ?